# Windows Disk Image (sysprep) with multiple domain accounts

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, domain, disk-image, sysprep

I have not a simple problem. I would like to make personalized sysprep (Windows disk image) for more than 50 windows domain account.

Suppose I have more than 50 computers with the same parameters, but uploading the image and log on to the domain user taking too long for each account/computer.
Of course, logging more than 50 users and then making Sysprep is not an option.
I would like to minimize my work - upload disk image into new HDD and be able to work without: change computer name, add domain name in computer properties section, restart, log on certain user account  etc.

How can I automate this process?

Any advice will be useful.
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Image is not tied to a domain account at all. The only **supported way** for personalization is to customize the Default profile. This is done by personalizing Local Administrator account and specifying that it's settings should be copied at the end of the SysPrep to the Default profile. This requires basic answer file.

You cannot skip renaming/joining/logging on. But you can automate most of these ops using MDT (automation) & WDS (delployment via network boot - F12).